# How do I fix the tax rate operation?

Tags: java

The goal is to provide the total sale, however, the tax rate is not calculating correctly since it keeps outputting 0.0.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Required for axquiring user's input

public class salesTax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int retailPrice; //Holds the retail price
        int taxRate; //Holds sales tax rate
        double salesTax; //Holds sales tax
        double totalSale; //Holds total sale
        
        //Scanner object to acquire user's input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Acquire user's retail price
        System.out.println("What is the retail price of the item being purchased? ");
        retailPrice = input.nextInt();
        
        //Acquire user's sales tax rate
        System.out.println("What is the sales tax rate? ");
        taxRate = input.nextInt() / 100;
        
        //Display the sales tax for the purchase
        salesTax = retailPrice * taxRate; //Calculates the sales tax
        System.out.println("The sales tax for the purchase is: " + salesTax);
        
        //Display the total of the sale
        totalSale = retailPrice + salesTax; //Calculate the total sale
        System.out.println("The total of the sale is: " + totalSale);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix the tax rate to produce accurate calculations, given that the tax rate is inputted by the user?

Comment: ```taxRate = input.nextInt() / 100;``` integer division gives you 0

Comment: Right now you have an integer tax rate, divided by 100. This results in integer division, which truncates to zero. Try dividing by 100.0.

Comment: @NomadMaker Your comment adds nothing to the answers already provided, but omits the fact that you need to declare `taxRate` as `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 3):

```
taxRate = input.nextInt() / 100;
```

This will give you 0 because you are dividing by an integer. You can take the number in as a float and divide by 100

```
float taxRate;
taxRate = input.nextFloat() / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the tax rate you are reading an integer from `System` input and you are dividing it by `100` which gives an integer result, I think you are entering values less than `100`. You need to read the values from the `scanner` as a `float`.

try this instead:

```
float taxRate;
taxRate = input.nextFloat() / 100;
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments the taxRate value is between `0` and `1`, so you should declare the `taxRate` as `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Your tax rate needs to be a `double` since you're dividing it by 100 and then assigning it `taxRate`. Since tax rate is an `int`, it will truncate the value leaving only the integer value.

If `taxRate = 7` and then you divide it by 100, you get `0.07`. Since `taxRate` is an Integer value, when Java sees said `0.07` it will get rid of the decimal and only leave the whole number. Therefore, say `taxRate = 3.9999`, since `taxRate` is an `int`, it will truncate the value leaving `3`. To fix this, change `taxRate` to a `double`.

Also, you need to read `taxRate` as a double value. To read a double value using Scanner, it will be `taxRate = input.nextDouble() / 100;`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. I fixed it!

Comment: Great - but now you just added the same answer a third time. :-?

Comment: I was in the middle of writing it... People beat me to it. A third solution won't hurt anyone.

Comment: Such is life. It's not really a third solution, though, it's *the same* solution three times...